# JSON Data does not appear when first run on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

i learn Android and create simple contact app.

When i use Custom Adapter, my data does not appear when first run on Android Studio. 
But it appears in Android Monitor's Log, and appear when run at second time on Android Emulator.
I use *Volley* for Http Client and render JSON data using *Jackson*.

This is my **Main Activity** :

```
package fanjavaid.com.contactapp;

...
...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView contactListView;
    private Context context;
    private ContactAdapter adapter;
    static List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Call API
        callContactsAPI();

        adapter = new ContactAdapter(this, contacts);
        contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        contactListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void callContactsAPI() {
        String url = "http://192.168.10.10/contacts";

        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {

                    if (objectMapper == null) {
                        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    }

                    // Jackson
                    contacts = Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(response.toString(), Contact[].class));
                    Log.i("Jackson Results : ", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(contacts));

                    // Important think!
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
    }
}
```

Thank you..

Comment: why are you calling the api *before* setting up the adapter and the list view?

Comment: @muratgu Cause i want call API and populate to `contacts` List first, and then inject it to adapter.

Comment: have you tried calling it after?

Comment: Already, still did not work